# Is there a way to test whether a Message object is in use?

Tags: android, exception, message

Random numbers are generated using the code below
Despite a call to message.recycle(); an AndroidRuntimeException is raised with the description - "This message is already in use" at the call to *sendMessage*(...)

Is there a way to test whether a Message is already in use? What am I doing wrong here?

```
RandomGenerator implements Runnable{
....
public void run(){
  ... 
    while(true){
        synchronized(randomizer){
            temp = randomizer.nextFloat() * scaleFactor;
        }

        Bundle bundleodata = new Bundle();
        bundleodata.putFloat( null, temp );

        synchronized(handler){
            Message messedUp = Message.obtain(handler);
            messedUp.setData(bundleodata);
            handler.sendMessage(messedUp);
        }
        Thread.yield();
    }
}
....
}
```

The body of the handler overrides handleMessage as follows

```
public void handleMessage( Message message ){
    String strStuff = Float.valueOf( message.getData(null).getFloat() ).toString();
    textVw.setText(strStuff);
    message.recycle();
}
```

EDIT: 
So after I removed 'message.recycle();' the exception is no longer thrown. However I'm still curious about why the exception is no longer thrown now that the call to recycle the object is removed. Ideas, anybody?

EDIT:
Replacing the call

```
msg.recycle();
```

with

```
removeMessages(0);
```

got the result I wanted i.e. update the text-view automagically. But I got to this stage empirically, rather than through logic/analysis. *It would be nice if we could work out why*

```
msg.recycle();
```

*resulted in the exception I reported originally*.

Comment: where is the exception raised ?

Answer (score 2):

It is an interesting question.  I have encountered the same issue in exactly the same context, i.e. inside a "handleMessage(Message message)" situation.  I believe it is because the message you are trying to recycle ("message") is integral to the declared handleMessage(Message message) method and will always be in use by that method.  "message" is not a local variable you are managing, but rather a variable always in use by the handleMessage() method...

Also see: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/9pHuc7lGunY
for discussion of why it is better not to call message.recycle().